# Input Double Value with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

how to input 2 value in database with ajax? or maybe you have another solution

php

```
$model_reservasi_detail = new TmReservasiDetail;
$model_reservasi_detail->IdReservasi = $model->IdReservasi;
$model_reservasi_detail->NoKamar =  $_POST["IdKamarBed"][$i];
$model_reservasi_detail->IdKamar =  $_POST["NoKamar"][$i];
```

ajax

```
html += "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' value='"+obj[key]["NoKamar"]+"' id='IdKamarBed_"+obj[key]["IdKamar"]+"' name='IdKamarBed[]'></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align='center'><b>"+obj[key]["NoKamar"]+"</td><td align='center'><b>"+obj[key]["Kapasitas"]+"</b></td>";
```

In that code only input NoKamar. How to input IdKamar too? i can only replace "NoKamar" with "IdKamar"

Comment: are you going to save html code '<td align="center ...' to save in database.... what

Comment: Please add the response of ajax in question.